# How can switch to an EC2 instance role locally as a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I apply ec2 instance roles to my servers but I want to switch to those roles myself locally first to test permissions

Id tried switching to one but I get an error:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/myrole --role-session abc

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/meeee is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/myrole
```

I am an account admin. Do I need to modify the trust policy or something to allow users to assume ec2 instance roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow your account to assume the service role you'll need to edit the role and add your account in the `Principal`.  To do so:

In `IAM` -> `Roles` -> `Your Service Role` go to the `Trust relationship` tab and click on `Edit trust relationship`.  Your trust relationship will something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to add your AWS account similar to this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<your AWS account number>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You will then be able to get credentials through `sts`.

Another way to get the desired outcome you're seeking is to use [Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/)

In the role's `Permissions` tab, click the arrow to the left of the policy and it will display a button to `Simulate policy`:

[image]

**NOTE**

It's not possible to use an IAM Group as a `Principal`.

> Note that a group is not truly an identity because it cannot be identified as a Principal in a resource-based or trust policy. It is only a way to attach policies to multiple users at one time.

#### References

- [Access Policies Testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)
- [Modifying a Role (Console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-managingrole-editing-console.html)
- [IAM User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html)

Comment: Is a group ARN an allowed principal for the trust policy?

Comment: @red888, No it's not.  I added a statement as to why in the body of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the credentials from the instance and use it locally with the help of [**get-instance-credentials**](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-utils/blob/master/get-instance-credentials) script.

1. Start your instance with the desired EC2 Role
2. Run `get-instance-credentials`

   ```sh
   [ec2-user@ip-...] aws-utils $ ./get-instance-credentials
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIA5G...ERJGI"
   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="8rTXu4R1...IM2"
   export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEE4aD...4zw=="
   ```
3. Copy and paste the 3 `export AWS_*` lines to your local shell on your laptop

   ```sh
   me@my-laptop ~ $ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIA5G...ERJGI"
   me@my-laptop ~ $ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="8rTXu4R1...IM2"
   me@my-laptop ~ $ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEE4aD...4zw=="
   ```
4. Verify the credentials

   ```sh
   me@my-laptop ~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity
   {
       "UserId": "AROAXYZABC1234:i-0a1b2c3d",
       "Account": "123456789012",
       "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/test-ec2-role/i-0a1b2c3d"
   }
   ```

As you can see even as **me@my-laptop** I can now access AWS with the credentials of **test-ec2-role**.

This way you can easily test the IAM Role configuration, test your apps, etc.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thats not very convenient as i need to stand up a server to do that. is there any way for a regular user account or another role to assume an instance role directly?

Comment: @red888 That’s what kenlukas’ answer describes. My answer shows how to bring the actual creds from the instance to a local shell for testing. At times it comes handy.